# How can i sent reponse back to postman in nodejs from a function?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, save, postman, response

I have a code which takes students details from json and insert to mongodb database. I have some validation checks in my schema for studentId unique etc.. when I save my data to mongodb I would like to get the response in postman, how can iget in postman, I tried below code to write response to poatman. Don't know if its correct, printing error in console is working, how can I get the same in postman?

```
function SaveToDatabase(student){ 
  student.save((err, student)=> {
     if(!err){
      console.log('insertion to db sucess')  
      res.send({ response: inserted });

     }
     else{
        console.log('insertion failed '+err);
        res.send({ error: err });
     }
  },function (err, inserted) {
    if (err) {
        res.send({ error: err });
    } else {
        res.send({ response: inserted });
    }
}
  );//save

}
```

Comment: res.send instead of student.send? Lines 5 and 10

Comment: getting res reference error

Comment: can we sent a response from fuction?

Comment: save function to db will return some response know, can I sent that response to postman from the same function itself. any posiibility like that?